# passing list elements to a post request using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, post

I am trying to send post request to a server using jquery ajax function.

My problem is the following: 
the cgi script (that i wanna avoid touching as much as possible) expects url with the following
format where list parameters are passed by declaring the parameter many times

for example for a given queryType "list":

> queryType=queryValue1&queryType=queryValue2&queryType=queryValue3

i fail to guess how to do this using the data field of the jquery ajax method without overriding
all parameters value by the last declared one.

Comment: Hi... could you post a code snippet of the ajax function. And what kind of field are you using for capturing the values?

Comment: Problem fixed,the bug was in the construction of the associative table that i supplied to the ajax.data field. jquery ajax itself does the job of expanding array into multiple parameter with no problem !